# What is the better form of movement for a vehicle that the player is inside of?

Tags: movement, unreal-4, unreal, loading

I am using unreal engine 4 to make this. Basically I have a submarine that the player can move around in and can control the submarines movement within an ocean. However I don't know the best way to implement movement of that submarine. I thought of several ideas. The first one being just moving the whole submarine model and all the objects inside of it within the terrain. However I am worried about moveable objects within the submarine glitching out because of this.

Another idea I had was setting a basic cube that is about the same size as the whole submarine model as a sort of "dummy" submarine that moves around the terrain and its movement is controlled by the controls inside of the actual submarine. However with this idea I don't know how having two areas loaded would work (the contents and models within the actual submarine and the terrain around the dummy one). Is it possible to have two loaded areas in an level at once? How can I implement it?

Comment: Which of these ideas have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Haven't tried either one yet, just asking which would be a better idea.

Comment: Whichever one works. So, try it first. If it works, you don't even have to ask!